# Folium - Map doesn't appear

Tags: python, folium

I try to get map through Folium but only thing I can see is marker on blank page.
I'd like to know where is problem lies, in explorer or coding.

map.py

```
import folium

map = folium.Map(location = [46.20, 6.144], zoom_start=6, tiles="Mapbox Bright")

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")
fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[40.12, 10.1], popup="Hi I'am a Marker", 
icon=folium.Icon(color='green')))
map.add_child(fg)

map.save("Map1.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the tiles name "Mapbox Bright". It seems that this kind of tiles is not supported by Folium/Leaflet anymore (without token). If you use one of the other tiles that are listed in the documentation, it will work :

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location = [46.20, 6.144], zoom_start=6, tiles="OpenStreetMap")

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")
fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[40.12, 10.1], popup="Hi I'am a Marker", 
icon=folium.Icon(color='green')))
m.add_child(fg)
m
```

It is better not to use `map` for the name of your map because it is a Python function and you are shadowing it (so you can't use it anymore).