# UK geojson displays blank folium map

Tags: geojson, folium

I'm trying to use the following geojson for UK local authorities, but it displays a blank map.

<https://martinjc.github.io/UK-GeoJSON/json/eng/topo_lad.json -O UK_counties.json>

My table lists most of the local authorities in the same way. Not sure if its the key_on reference that's the only problem or if there's more to it.

My code so far is below:

```
threshold_scale = np.linspace(df_ctbl['Population'].min(), df_ctbl['Population'].max(), 6, dtype=int)

threshold_scale = threshold_scale.tolist() # change the numpy array to a list
threshold_scale[-1] = threshold_scale[-1] + 1 # make sure that the last value of the list is greater than the maximum immigration

# let Folium determine the scale.
londonf_map = folium.Map(location=[latitudeld, longitudeld], zoom_start=4, tiles='Mapbox Bright')
londonf_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=uk_geo,
    data=df_ctbl,
    columns=['Local Authorityp', 'Population'],
    key_on= 'properties.lad13nm',
    threshold_scale=threshold_scale,
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='UK Population in 2019',
    reset=True
)
londonf_map
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this answer : [question about Mapbox bright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64373165/folium-map-doesnt-appear/64374124#64374124). I think you have a problem with the tiles name "Mapbox Bright".

Comment: That showed boundaries but did not include my data as a heat map